# Export Visual Studio Extension Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-essentials

Is it possible to export the settings for a Visual Studio extension (as opposed to the extension itself)?

For example I'm using the [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) extension which integrates it's settings into the Visual Studio options. I'd like copy just these settings.